# Spring Boot: Execute SQL for non-entity Classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

What I am trying to perform is the following:
I have some complex SQL (with  SUM(distance) distanceSum as identifier for the returned columnd) that returns some values that should be parsed to a class (containing just the values needed for these columns).
However, I only need the result in memory and not as entity.
I already tried to create a repository to execute the SQL with a @Query annotation with native = true. However, the repository can't be autowired, probably because Repositories are only meant for entities.

So is there some way to tweak a repository for non-entities or is there a approach other than repositories that would let me execute SQL and parse the result automatically into an object.

Comment: That's what JdbcTemplate is for. It has methods to execute native SQL statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically as @dunni said you can use the `JdbcTemplate` with your own mapper to convert the SQL result to Java POJO:

```
public CustomResult getCustomResult(){
    final String complexSql = "SELECT SUM(distance) as distanceSum....";
    final CustomResult customResult = (CustomResult) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(complexSql, new CustomResultRowMapper());

    return customResult;
}

public class CustomResultRowMapper implements RowMapper {
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        CustomResult customResult = new CustomResult();
        customResult.setDistanceSum(rs.getInt("distanceSum"));
        ...
        return customResult;
    }
}
```

Also in Spring Boot you don't need to do anything just add your `jdbcTemplate` to your Dao class:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just was I was looking for, it seems I just wasn't able to use the correct searchterms when googling